# do all vector spaces function under ordinary component wise addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

All the vector spaces I have seen so far in my class have ordinary component wise addition.  This means I can add the corresponding components of vectors or matrices or polynomials, etc.  But are there cases where the addition is not really the familiar component addition but rather something different than wise addition like function composition or something like that?

Comment: the set of all real continuous functions forms a vector space with the usual addition (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) and scalar multiplication (cf)(x)=cf(x)

Comment: [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Generalizations).

Comment: @LiChunMin that's still pointwise == coordinatewise addition.

Comment: All vector space addition is just componentwise addition wrt a basis. This is what bases are for.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma For the case of (not finite dimensional) vector spaces of functions, you can no longer speak of decomposition on a basis, in the general case.

Comment: but I think by "not ordinary componentwise addition", the op is requesting for examples where the vectors cannot be represented by some linear combination of basis vectors such that each vector can be represented by some coordinates and can be added componentwise…can we represent each continuous function by a basis of continuous functions without resorting to infinite sum?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, you can. You just use finite sums.

Comment: @LiChunMin a basis uses only finite sums of course. But the OP examples are also infinite vectors, and there a linear basis is pretty useless